# Extend lodash/underscore on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, underscore.js, lodash

Lodash and Underscore have a method called mixin that allow you to extend the libraries. How do you write a library that will extend them?

For example, if you created a file called "extend_lodash.js", with the following content:

```
_.mixin({
   new_function:function(){}
})
```

How would you work with it on your project? The code below won't work:

```
_ = require("lodash");
require("extend_lodash.js");
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: It obviously doesn't work because "_" is not defined inside extend_lodash.js (throwing that error), because node.js isolate the namespaces. I'd have to call eval(fs.readFileSync("extend_lodash.js")) if I wanted the expected effect.

Comment: Or you could require `lodash` in your `extend_lodash.js` file?

Comment: I could, but then it wouldn't affect the lodash loaded on the main file at all.

Comment: Why not put lodash and your extensions in one place and then require that instead of lodash? Then you'll always get your extended lodash and you can move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: @Dokkat: I believe that would work (because of the require() cache)

Comment: @muistooshort, I don't know, the actual question seems to me to be "how does _.mixin work, and why doesn't it work in this case?". Which is certainly an interesting problem to me.

Answer (score 6):

As 'mu is too short' also suggests, have your file with the lodash mixin return lodash.

In your "extend_lodash.js" file:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
_.mixin({
  new_function:function(){}
});
module.exports = _;
```

And then in the caller, you just require your mixin and get lodash from that:

```
var _ = require("extend_lodash");
```